# Obliterate the main query and replace it

Tags: pre-get-posts

There are lots of [good resources](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) on how to alter the main query, or add secondary loops...

But I actually want to completely replace the main query with a different query altogether.

I am hijacking one of my pages to serve, essentially, as a category page. (Note I am changing from "page" to "post" in my effort to do this.) But when I alter the main query by doing this:

```
function front_page_announcements( $query ) {
    if ( $query->query_vars['page_id'] == 84 && $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin ) {
        $query->set("category_name", "special-announcement");
        $query->set("page_id", NULL);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'front_page_announcements' );
```

I end up getting every page (not post) in the database. What I actually want is every post (not page) with a category id of `3`, or `special-announcement` in my case.

I don't want to make unnecessary calls to the database, so it seems like the `pre_get_posts` action hook is what I'll want, but I can't figure it out. Even just setting `$query = new WP_Query('cat=3')` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When `'pre_get_posts'` is fired, there are a lot of things that WordPress has already done like setup all the query variables (also the query you don't send) and setup all the conditional properties (all the `is_*` properties). So, if you want *completely* replace the query you should reset all that things and set your own.

In fact, even if your code works, WordPress will use `page.php` as template.

However there's a simpler approach: act *before* WordPress do all the things.

A good place is the `'request'` filter hook, at that time WordPress has created the query vars from url and is going to pass that vars to `WP_Query`, and you can intercept and change query arguments before are sent.

That action is fired by `WP` class, and pass the query vars to be set ([see code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L324)).

```
add_filter( 'request', function( array $query_vars ) {

  // triggered also in admin pages
  if ( is_admin() )
    return $query_vars;

  // you should check also for page slug, because when pretty permalink are active
  // WordPress use 'pagename' query vars, not 'page_id'
  $id = isset($query_vars['page_id']) && (int) $query_vars['page_id'] === 84;
  // remember to replace "slug" with real page slug
  $name = isset($query_vars['pagename']) && $query_vars['pagename'] === 'slug';

  if ( ( $id || $name)  && ! isset($query_vars['error']) ) {
    $query_vars = array('category_name' => 'special-announcement');
  }

  return $query_vars;

});
```

Replace `'slug'` with the real slug of your page, then let WordPress do its work.

Note that I've not check for main query, because `'request'` is triggered only for main query.

If you want to use a specific template, you should use a filter on [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) otherwise `'category.php'` (or the right template according to [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)) will be used.

Comment: Works great! I am on (and want to stay on) `front-page.php` for this task, and it looks as though the front page has zero `query_vars`. So I added `empty($wp->query_vars)` to the if statement.

`if ( $id || $name || empty($wp->query_vars) ) { `...

And I did end up using `template_include` to force WordPress to *stay* on (or, rather, choose) `front-page.php`.

Comment: A word to the wise for anyone who finds this question/answer useful: the answer above uses php 5.3.0+ [Anonymous Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and as of this writing, WordPress only [requires](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) php 5.2.4 so alter the code as needed. Using the answer (anon function) and the question (pure callback) as examples, you should be fine.