# pre_get_posts Remove tax_query Completely

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts, tax-query

I'm using `pre_get_posts` to filter by using `$wp_query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );`

**I'm probably better-off doing this with a `new WP_Query`, but if someone knows something I don't I'd love to hear it**

Problem, I need to set a default taxonomy & preserve the ability to show all posts.

For instance:

`/cpt/?taxo=this` shows all cpt's which have a taxo-term == this.

```
$taxo_terms = [];
if( !empty( $_GET['taxo'] ) ){
  $types = explode(',', $_GET['taxo']);
  foreach ($types as $key => $val) {
    $taxo_terms[$key] = sanitize_key($val);
  }
}
else{
    $taxo_terms[]='this'; // here's where things get ugly.
}

$tax_query = [];
if( !empty($taxo_terms) ){
  $tax_query[] = [
    'taxonomy' => 'taxo',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $taxo_terms,
    'operator' => 'AND',
  ];
  $wp_query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
```

I want to add `/cpt/?taxo=all` to show all posts, regardless of what `taxo->terms` they have.

Hoping to find a way to `unset` the current `tax_query` from the loop, using `pre_get_posts`.

Is there a way to `$wp_query->UNSET`?

I've tried `$wp_query->set( 'tax_query', null );`

Comment: Log all of the contents of the `$wp_query` object inside that filter, taxonomy queries are referenced in multiple places in there. I think you have to manually unset the tax query object that gets created before the filter runs, which is separate from the tax query var that `set` modifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed it! :) Hat-tip [gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/gmazzap) for the useful info: [Obliterate the main query and replace it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/obliterate-the-main-query-and-replace-it#answer-139837)

```
function wpse_286813_omit_all( $query_vars ){

  // triggered also in admin pages
  if ( is_admin() )
    return $query_vars;

  if( !empty($query_vars['taxo']) && $query_vars['taxo'] === 'all' ){
    $query_vars['taxo']='';
  }
  return $query_vars;

}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse_286813_omit_all' );
```